# To Calculate Kinetic Energy of slippping chain overhanging over a smooth table as a function of length of overhang

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, potential-energy, string

Is it even possible to do so? (With only upto highschool level knowledge of mechanics ie without the use of things like Lagrangian mechanics if that is even useful here).

I know how the mass will be changing with the overhang length but cannot understand how to do so for the velocity.

Details of the question:

Mass of Chain = *m*

Total Chain Length = *l*

Length of chain initially overhanging = *(l/3)*

Comment: Yes, it can be done by elementary calculus as shown below. The problem can also be found in 'Problems in General Physics' by I.E. Irodov, a problem book meant for preparation of high school physics olympiads.

Comment: @PhysicsMonster_01 Oh, I didn't know that. My physics instructor told me that this chapter had been mixed in with that of momentum and collisions (which we hadn't studied yet) in Irodov so I was avoiding it for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with plain calculus. Take $x$ to be the length of the hanging part of the chain and $\rho$ to be the chain's linear density $m/l$. The change in kinetic energy is equal to the amount of work done by gravity on the chain.

$$K = \int_{x_0}^x F(s)\textrm{d}s = \int_{x_0}^x s\rho g \textrm{d}s = \frac{1}{2}\rho g(x^2 - x_0^2.)$$

Here, $x_0$ is the length of chain initially overhanging, so that is given as $l/3$, so the final expression is
$$K = \frac{1}{2}\rho g \left(x^2 - \left(\frac{l}{3}\right)^2\right).$$
Note: this formula stops being correct once $x > l$.

Answer (score 1):

Not with high-school-only math.

Use differential equations, one can solve this initial value problem:

Say total length is L.
$$\frac{d^2l}{dt^2}=\frac l L g$$ with initial condition $l(0) =\frac 1 3L$,  $l'(0) =0$ (zero initial velocity)

Now one have $l(t)$, one can calculate the kinetic energy of the chain at the time $t^*$.

$$KE=\frac 1 2 m \left(\left.\frac {dl}{dt}\right\vert _{t^*}\right) ^2$$

#### Appendix

Solve $\frac{d^2l}{dt^2}=\frac l L g$
$$l''(t)-\frac g L l=0$$
Notice that it is homogenous and linear.
The characteristic polynomial is $$x^2-\frac g L=0$$
which has two distinct real roots
$$x_{1,2}=\pm\sqrt{\frac g L}$$
so the solution is
$$l=C_1e^{-\sqrt{\frac g L}t}+C_2e^{\sqrt{\frac g L}t}$$

Comment: I actually happen to know the basics of differential equations. So could you please explain this in a little more detail?

Comment: @Limbo I have updated my answer. The solution is in the appendix.

Comment: @Limbo Sorry I found out a serious mistake in my answer. I have updated it so now it should be correct

Comment: While this answer is entirely correct, it does illustrate how working purely in energy can avoid the complexities of time-dependent motion.